# Compare Source CSV file row count to counts recorded in a Summary file

Tags: oracle-adf

Inside a Azure ADF pipeline, I need to find and compare the count of the CSV file stored in Azure Blob storage to a Summary file also in the Blob storage which has counts for all the files. If say for example, I have a source file F1.csv, I need to compare the count stored in the Summary file for the particular file name, F1.csv.

If the comparison fails then pipeline will stop, if the counts match then can proceed ahead in the pipeline.

I checked the GetMetadata activity but it doesnt work how I want it, meaning it is not able to read the content of the Summary file to be able to compare it with the Source file count.